# Library for RSA implementation in pure C

Tags: c, rsa, signal-processing

I'm looking for a very simple implementation of RSA in C. I need to place it in a DSP, so I'd like to use something very thin and straightforward.
Nonetheless, I just found only examples with little numbers (int or long) while I need to implement RSA at least at 1024 bits, so I also have to cope with large numbers.

Can you point me to some libraries or examples for this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [LibTomCrypt](http://www.libtom.net/?page=features&newsitems=5&whatfile=crypt) and related projects are very clean and understandable.

Comment: apparently, the web site has moved to here -> http://www.libtom.net/?page=features&newsitems=5&whatfile=crypt

Answer (score 2):

The [latest openssl release's source](http://openssl.org/source/openssl-1.0.1c.tar.gz) contains an implementation of RSA, which should work fine for your purposes. Alternatively, you may also consider the [GNUPg](http://gnupg.org) project, another open-source project with an RSA component.